# What is the fastest (most reliable) way to calculate the Frenet frame, curvature and torsion, given r(t)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Vector calculus, just learned about the Frenet frame and curvature and torsion. Naturally, we have to calculate a lot of these on homework and exams. However, the formulas that we are given for getting curvature, torsion, frame are computationally intensive and usually requires a whole bunch of different calculations (differentiate twice, take a cross product and two absolute values just for $\kappa$ and $\tau$). Being unreliable as a biological computer, I am fairly error prone. It feels like there should be easier and more direct ways of getting these formulae. We have:

$\mathrm T=\frac{\mathrm r^\prime}{|r^\prime|}$, $\mathrm B=\frac{\mathrm{r'(\mathit t)\times r''(\mathit t)}}{|\mathrm{r'(\mathit t)\times r''(\mathit t)}|}$, $\mathrm{N=B\times T}$, $\kappa =\frac{|\mathrm{r'(\mathit t)\times r''(\mathit t)}|}{\mathrm |r'(t)|^3}$, $\tau=\frac{(\mathrm{r'(\mathit t)\times r''(\mathit t)})\cdot \mathrm r'''(t)}{|\mathrm{r'(\mathit t)\times r''(\mathit t)}|^2}$
and the Frenet-Serret formulas.

I am not sure what strategy I should go for - calculate the unit tangent, differentiate a whole bunch, and take absolute values (go straight for Frennet-Serret) or should I try the given formulas since I have a function with respect to t and not arc length? Is there some other better faster way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The sequence you suggest is pretty minimal. I tell students to avoid finding $\mathbf{N}$ by finding $\mathbf{T}^\prime/|\mathbf{T}^\prime|$ since this computation can be rather involved. Using $\mathbf N=\mathbf B\times \mathbf T$ is usually cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

The formulas you cited are the best ones, as far as I know. Just find the first three derivatives wrt the parameter $t$, and compute away (sorry). Either be careful, or use some symbolic math software to help you (though I expect this might be frowned upon).

The work is not quite as laborious as it seems at first, because there are quite a lot of repeated/shared terms in the equations. Just make sure you only compute these quantities once.

The formulas that involve derivatives with respect to arclength are fairly useless in practice because (outside of differential geometry textbooks) curves are hardly ever parameterized by arclength.